# Combinatoric for number of ways to have monotone-increasing sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory

I hope I am using the right term. By monotone-increasing I mean to imply that it is a non-decreasing sequence. So for example a sequence $1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 10, 10, 11$, etc.

Anyhow, consider a monotone-increasing sequence of length $k$ such that each element of the sequence is a number bound between $1$ and $n$.

The number of ways to construct such a sequence is $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$, which I found with experimentation, but I'd like to understand why this is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since any choice at all can be sorted as non-decreasing in a unique way, your question is the same as "what's the number of ways to choose k objects out of n with replacement."  That has been well studied...a simple proof that your formula works can be found, e.g., here:

http://www.johndcook.com/blog/select_with_replacement/

Comment: "Since any choice at all can be sorted as non-decreasing in a unique way" Can you elaborate on what you mean by this?

Comment: Sure.  I am saying that there is a 1:1 correspondence between your sequences and the unordered collection obtained by choosing from {1, ...,n} with replacement.  The correspondence is:  "Take the unordered collection and sort it in increasing order."  That gives me a sequence of your type.  You have to argue that this association is injective, but that's clear, isn't it?  Any unordered collection is uniquely determined by the number of 1's, 2's, .... etc.