# I wonder if there is a simple formula for $\#\{(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in\mathbb{Z}^n\mid a\leq a_1\leq\dots\leq a_n\leq b\}$.

Tags: combinatorics

I solved the following problem by a brute-force method and I wanted to estimate $\#\{(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in\mathbb{Z}^n\mid a\leq a_1\leq\dots\leq a_n\leq b\}$ before I make my program for this problem.

https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc165/tasks/abc165_c

I wonder if there is a simple formula for $\#\{(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in\mathbb{Z}^n\mid a\leq a_1\leq\dots\leq a_n\leq b\}$.

> Let $a, b$ be integers such that $a\leq b$.
> Find a simple formula for
> $\#\{(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in\mathbb{Z}^n\mid a\leq a_1\leq\dots\leq a_n\leq b\}.$

Obviously, we need to find a simple formula only for $\#\{(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in\mathbb{Z}^n\mid 0\leq a_1\leq\dots\leq a_n\leq m\}.$

But I have no idea at all.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1370040/combinatoric-for-number-of-ways-to-have-monotone-increasing-sequence

Comment: @JensSchwaiger Thank you very much for your link.